Error saving metadata: Script-thrown exception
I'm trying to create a form that create record using Salesforce Metadata API. The LWC, JS, and controller apex classes are all set up correctly. I have already checked the gitHub repo and added MetadataService and MetadataServiceTest classes to my project. and it throws Script-thrown exception.
this is the LWC
    <template>
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <header class="slds-modal__header">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-inverse slds-modal__close" title="Close" onclick={handleCloseModal}>
                    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" alternative-text="close" size="small"></lightning-icon>
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">SFTP Login Credentials</h2>
            </header>

            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
                    <lightning-input 
                        label="Server Address" 
                        name="server" 
                        value={server} 
                        onchange={handleInputChange} 
                        required>
                    </lightning-input>

                    <lightning-input 
                        label="Username" 
                        name="username" 
                        value={username} 
                        onchange={handleInputChange} 
                        required>
                    </lightning-input>

                    <lightning-input 
                        label="Password" 
                        name="password" 
                        type="password" 
                        value={password} 
                        onchange={handleInputChange} 
                        required>
                    </lightning-input>
                </div>
            </div>

            <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick={handleCloseModal}></lightning-button>
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick={handleSave}></lightning-button>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
</template>

and this is the JS file
    import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import createSftpMetadataRecord from '@salesforce/apex/SftpMetadataController.createSftpMetadataRecord';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class SftpMetadataForm extends LightningElement {
    @track server = '';
    @track username = '';
    @track password = '';

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const field = event.target.name;
        if (field === 'server') {
            this.server = event.target.value;
        } else if (field === 'username') {
            this.username = event.target.value;
        } else if (field === 'password') {
            this.password = event.target.value;
        }
    }

    async handleSave() {
        if (this.validateInputs()) {
            try {
                const result = await createSftpMetadataRecord({
                    server: this.server,
                    username: this.username,
                    password: this.password
                });

                this.showToast('Success', result, 'success');
                this.handleCloseModal();
            } catch (error) {
                this.showToast('Error', error.body.message, 'error');
            }
        } else {
            this.showToast('Error', 'Please complete all required fields.', 'error');
        }
    }

    validateInputs() {
        return this.server && this.username && this.password;
    }

    handleCloseModal() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('close'));
    }

    showToast(title, message, variant) {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            variant: variant
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}

and this is the controller
    /**
 * @file SftpMetadataController.cls
 * @description Apex class to handle creation of SFTP credentials custom metadata records.
 * @date 
 */

 public with sharing class SftpMetadataController {
    /**
     * Inserts a custom metadata record of type SFTP_Login_Credential__mdt.
     * @param serverAddress The server address for the SFTP.
     * @param username The username for the SFTP login.
     * @param password The password for the SFTP login.
     * @return A string message indicating success or error.
     */
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String createSftpMetadataRecord(String serverAddress, String username, String password) {
        // Ensure Metadata API is available
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();

        // Define new custom metadata record with proper namespace prefix if needed
        MetadataService.CustomMetadata customMetadata = new MetadataService.CustomMetadata();
        customMetadata.fullName = 'SFTP_Login_Credential__mdt.SFTP_Credentials';  // Update with the unique full name
        
        // Set field values for the custom metadata record
        customMetadata.values = new List<MetadataService.CustomMetadataValue>();
        customMetadata.values.add(createCustomMetadataValue('server__c', serverAddress));
        customMetadata.values.add(createCustomMetadataValue('username__c', username));
        customMetadata.values.add(createCustomMetadataValue('password__c', password));

        try {
            // Call Metadata API to create the metadata record
            MetadataService.SaveResult[] results = service.createMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customMetadata });
            
            // Check for success or capture error message
            if (results != null && results[0].success) {
                return 'SFTP Login Credential created successfully.';
            } else if (results != null && !results[0].success && results[0].errors != null) {
                return 'Error creating metadata: ' + results[0].errors[0].message;
            } else {
                return 'Unknown error while creating metadata.';
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log exception for further debugging and return error message
            System.debug('Exception in createSftpMetadataRecord: ' + e.getMessage());
            return 'Exception: ' + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Helper method to create a CustomMetadataValue object for a specific field and value.
     * @param field The API name of the custom metadata field.
     * @param value The value to be set in the field.
     * @return CustomMetadataValue instance.
     */
    private static MetadataService.CustomMetadataValue createCustomMetadataValue(String field, String value) {
        MetadataService.CustomMetadataValue cmdValue = new MetadataService.CustomMetadataValue();
        cmdValue.field = field;
        cmdValue.value = value;
        return cmdValue;
    }
    /**
     * Helper method to initialize Metadata API service
     */
    public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService(){
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        //service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = Utils.getSessionIdFromVFPage(Page.SessionId);
        return service;
    }
}


You're going to need to [edit] your question to add more details. Showing us the LWC and Apex you currently have will be helpful. Assuming you're getting this error when the Apex portion is being executed, you'll want to open the developer console so you can look at the execution log and get a better idea of what the error is ("script thrown exception" is so broad/vague that nobody can really tell you why you're getting it).

I made the update as requested

You also need to include the console log errors, and perhaps also capture a debug log on your Apex using Setup > Debug Log.

I couldn't add the debug log there, and this is what I get in the console
"Exception: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: Cannot invoke "common.udd.EntityInfo.getApiElementInfoByApiName(String, common.udd.UddMode, boolean)" because the return value of "customplatform.mdapi.CustomMetadata.getEntityInfo()" is null Error Id: 1400852680-213906 (1461513609) faultcode=soapenv:Server faultactor=
"
